# In a scheduled Dataprep Job is it possible to export an output csv in Data Storage with suffix-based name?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataprep

I would like to schedule a daily Google DataPrep job exporting csv files into a Storage Bucket. These csv files should contain instead of the incremental number proposed by the console (ex. output.csv, output_1.csv, output_2.csv..) a date-based suffix (ex. output20190211.csv, output20190212.csv, output20190213.csv..).
Is it possible?

Comment: Hello and welcome!
Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @OneLunchMan yes I tried with the console and the only option when creating a new file in Data Storage for each job run, is to add an incremental number appended to the prefix name chose. I would prefer instead to append a date-based-suffix.

Comment: Please add your steps attempted (a detailed version) to the question, it'll help people know where you are/what exactly you're working with. You may also have more luck with an answer by tailoring your question to a specific programming problem instead of possible vs not. Happy coding!